# Equivalent of Condvar for tokio tasks

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm using a framework that relies on the `tokio` runtime and I cannot use the `current_thread` variant of the runtime.
I also use a foreign language interface, which gives me some restrictions regarding threads: I have a resource which only can exist once per thread, if not I'm risking undefined behavior.

Currently, I'm solving the problem like this:

```rust
async fn use_the_resource(parameter: String,....) {
    while resource_exists_on_thread() {
        tokio::task::yield_now().await;
    }
    resource = create_resource(); //this will lead to undefined behavior, if a resource exists on the same thread
    use_resource(resource, parameter,...);
}
```

But this does not seem to be the optimal solution. I'd like to have a mechanism similar to `std::sync::Condvar`, but for tasks instead for threads. This would allow me to let the task wait until my resource gets available. I cannot really use a `Mutex`, since I don't control thread creation.

Comment: Can you have one instance of the resource for the whole program? If so, maybe you can spawn a task whose single purpose is to handle this resource, and communicate with it via mpsc channels?

Comment: _"but for tasks instead for threads"_ -- But if it's per task that won't solve the problem, will it? Because tasks can move between threads, and multiple tasks can be running on the same thread.

Comment: @cdhowie If the task moves to another thread where the resource is not around, it could resume. The behavior I want to see is something like the `wait_until` from `Condvar` which only stops the task instead of blocking the thread. But it might simply be impossible (how would notifications work after a task has moved?).

Comment: @ixolius Right, having a task move mid-wait is a problem. Tokio's work-stealing model doesn't seem like a good fit for your use case. You might consider `tokio::spawn_blocking` instead for the part of the task that uses the "thread-locked" resource.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you're looking for is https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/struct.Notify.html.

Your snippet would roughly translate to:

```rust
async fn use_the_resource(parameter: String, ...) {
    resource_used_by_thread.await;
    resource = create_resource(...);
    use_resource(&resource, parameter, ...);
}
```

Comment: Except... That the task can be moved to a different thread after the `Notify` and then you'll have UB.